# Unable to redirect to some pages using AngularJS routeProvider

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to code a spring boot application based in Angularjs.
I have a project structure as follows:

[image: project structure eclipse][1]

The controller calls the index.html perfectly:

[image: controller]

the app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','ngResource']);
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/users',{
            templateUrl: 'views/users.html',
            controller: 'usersController'
        })
        .when('/roles',{
            templateUrl: 'views/roles.html',
            controller: 'rolesController'
        })
        .otherwise(
            { redirectTo: '/'}
        );
});
```

I get the first page when running the app but when I click on the links users and roles, nothing happens.

UPDATED:
the index.html is:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Spring boot and Angularjs Tutorial</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
</head>
<body>
<h2>Administrator Panel</h2>
<div class="home-section">
    <ul class="menu-list">
        <li><a href="#/users">Users</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/roles">Roles</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div ng-view></div>
<script src="/lib/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/angular-route.js"></script>

<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="/js/controller.js"></script>



<link href="/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</body>
</html>
```

How can I fix this issue.

[1]:

Comment: Can you post your html link?

Comment: i updated my question with index.html

Comment: What is your angular version?

Comment: i working with version 1.6.6

Comment: Change your href like this <li><a href="#!users">Users</a></li>

Comment: i tried to change the logic when moving from page to page using the stateProviderService , maybe this is the point

Answer (score 0):

For link in AngularJS you should use `ng-href` directive: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref

Ex.

```
<a ng-href="#/users">Users</a>
```

Comment: i tried it and it came with a non linked url but as a label.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="menu-list">
    <li><a ui-sref="users">Users</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="roles">Roles</a></li>
</ul>
```

Try this one. You can use `ui-sref` for navigation from html page

Comment: seems the links came as labels , i cannot click on them.

Comment: You havn't mentioned `ng-app` and `ng-controller` in index.html

Comment: no there is the html tag :
<html lang="en" ng-app="app" class="no-js"> 
and the ng-controller is dfifined in the app.js

Comment: in index.html provide `<body data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="myCtrl">` this will be considered as a root controller for the whole app. it seems you are talking about nested controller

Comment: define `ng-controller` in index.html not in app.js

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared **ng-app="app"** at beginning of your template?

Comment: yes here is as in the index.html:
<html lang="en" ng-app="app" class="no-js">

Comment: seems you are missing 'master controller'  for the entire app. 

Try this:

    <body ng-controller="MasterController">

ngRoute works well inside the scope of application. So, you need to have one main controller which will handle the entire application.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i fixed this issue:

```
<div class="list-group">
                        <a href="#home" class="list-group-item"
                            ng-class="{active: currentNavLink == '/home'}"> <i
                            class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;Home
                        </a> <a href="#contacts" class="list-group-item"
                            ng-class="{active: currentNavLink == '/contacts'}"> <i
                            class="fa fa-user fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;Contacts
                        </a> <a href="#todos" class="list-group-item"
                            ng-class="{active: currentNavLink == '/todos'}"> <i
                            class="fa fa-indent fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;ToDos
                        </a>


                    </div>
```

where in the app.js:

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.when('', '/home');
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    /*
    $urlRouterProvider.rule(function($injector, $location) {
      return '/home';
    });
    */
    $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    })
    .state('contacts', {
        url: '/contacts',
        templateUrl: 'templates/contacts.html',
        controller: 'ContactController'
    })  
    .state('todos', {
        url: '/todos',
        templateUrl: 'templates/todos.html',
        controller: 'TodoController'
    })
```